# Что быстрее DROP TABLE или TRUNCATE TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, при извлечении процедуры создается временная таблица #, заполняется какими-то данными.

Если процедура запускается вновь, то происходит DROP этой переменной таблицы и она снова создается и наполняется данными.

Структура таблицы не меняется.

Будет ли профит если из временной таблицы создать нормальную таблицу и вместо DROP делать TRUNCATE?

Comment: То есть, вы уже определили, что это самое узкое место в Вашей процедуре? А то есть подозрение, что по сравнению с остальной частью процедуры удаление (или очистка) таблицы будет занимать пренебрежимо малое время. Тут скорее надо руководствоваться соображениями бизнес-логики. Например, если есть вероятность, что процедура может быть запущена одновременно двумя пользователями, то однозначно надо использовать временные таблицы (иначе рискуете столкнуться с ситуацией, когда одна процедура заполнила таблицу своими данными, и в этот момент вторая ее очистит).

Comment: В 90% случаев когда делают временные таблицы они на самом деле не нужны и можно обойтись единым запросом. И это обычно быстрее чем таблицы

Comment: А зачем хранить состояние временной таблицы между вызовами процедуры?

Comment: @Anatol, а как его вообще можно сохранить? Что-то я не знал такого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее `truncate` должен быть несколько быстрее, чем `drop` (и тем более, чем пара `drop` + `create`), т.к. `truncate` лишь изменяет сведения о пространстве, выделенном для хранения данных таблицы, переводя его из состояния занятого в свободное. Тогда как `drop` делает то же самое, но вдобавок ещё и удаляет сведения об объекте (записи в системных таблицах о том, что существует такая-то таблица с таким-то набором столбцов).

Однако, как справедливо отметили в комментариях, на практике затраты что на одно, что на другое могут быть пренебрежимо малы по сравнению с другими операциями в процедуре.

Вдобавок, я бы поостерегся того, чтобы

> из временной таблицы создать нормальную таблицу

даже если есть уверенность, что не будет конфликтов из-за параллельного доступа, т.к. временные таблицы "живут" в системной базе данных *tempdb*, а в ней применяются дополнительные меры для повышения производительности ([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms190768.aspx), см. раздел *Увеличение производительности базы данных tempdb*).

Answer (score 0):

TRUNCATE очищает таблицу не добавляя записи  в журнал транзакций. Это быстрей чем DROP-CREATE. Но как было замечено, важно что будут возникать проблемы при совместном использовании таблицы несколькими процессами.

Comment: `truncate [table]` _добавляет_ записи в журнал транзакций, но протоколирование `truncate` более "легковесная" операция, чем `delete from [table]`.